# How to optimize duplicate TS checks if the value may be undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, optimization

Can the following code be simplified for readability, simplicity, or any other way? Specifically, can this be written without checking for `undefined` on every line?

These `ok` statements are only some of the many filters that are checked, so this list is large and unruly.

```
  const aOk = data?.a ? data.a.includes(a) : true
  const bOk = data?.b ? data.b <= b : true
  const cOk = data?.c ? data.c >= c : true
  const dOk = data?.d ? data.d === d : true
  const eOk = data?.e ? data.e === e.toString() : true

  if (
    aOk &&
    bOk &&
    cOk &&
    dOk &&
    eOk
  ) {
    return true
  }

  return false
```

Comment: Computers don’t even feel 5 statements. A change for speed is most likely premature optimization. I would instead focus on readability.

Comment: That is what I am going for. I am going to update the question accordingly.

Comment: "*this list is large and unruly*" - do you actually have a *list* of something? What is the actual code doing? Where do the variables `a` through `e` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shape of validation doesn't change often, I don't see a problem with your function. As another poster mentioned you can instead create a list of functions. Something like this:

```
type TData = {
  a: number[];
  b: number;
  c: number;
  d: number;
  e: string;
};

const data = {
  a: [3],
  b: 4,
  c: 4,
  d: 1,
  e: "9",
};

const validators: (data:TData, v: { [k in keyof TData]: number }) => {
  [k in keyof TData]: () => boolean;
} = (v) => ({
  a: () => data.a.includes(v.a),
  b: () => data.b <= v.b,
  c: () => data.c >= v.c,
  d: () => data.d === v.d,
  e: () => data.e === v.e.toString(),
});

const all = () => {
  for (const k of Object.values(validators(data, otherData))) {
    if (!k()) return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper function such as

```js
const fn = (data) = (key, op, value) =>
  data[key] ? op(data[key], value) : true
```

Then you can define a set of functions that do the comparisons you need. This might remove repetition, and improve maintainability. You may be able to use something like `operations[key](this[key], data[key])` if your variables in data and the scope match up.

```js
const comp = fn(data)

const aOk = comp(‘a’, myIncludes, a)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems clear and is readable to me:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3lAXPFArgLYBGIMA3AFCiSwLLpYl6GnnW3RyKqaKtiZSjXDcGfLMEHsRXerybwQM4dSoYAngAcEAESgYoAHgAqAPngBeeAG8q8bAH48t+AEsUkAqDR4AFABuUBAEKvAEKADWKEgA7igAlNaWJEhIECBQKPAAvtSOJC7wpgWIxaUO8MAVZSDFmDCeAObU+VSidDyM-MCGuPAGRsZswubqPVghEADyUdbwAELpmdn+VX1GTgB0UPBO1f27257evv5QyXgYMGFVAGT3h1vbJPvPUK-wxjZv17cgB5PTZQHZgd4g7bg8w2cH-O6OR4fHbACFHVFWTHVeDwwGI4H9HYIA6QhCYmwgbYYJAAZRuLX8V3gNzuiWoQA)

```ts
const allOk = Boolean(
  data?.a ? data.a.includes(a) : true
  && data?.b ? data.b <= b : true
  && data?.c ? data.c >= c : true
  && data?.d ? data.d === d : true
  && data?.e ? data.e === e.toString() : true
);
```

Comment: Calling `Boolean` on a boolean doesn't make sense

Comment: @Bergi Why not? `typeof Boolean(true) === typeof true`

Comment: Exactly - it does nothing here, so you should just omit it

Comment: @Bergi I disagree: I think the improved readability of this pattern and flexibility of allowing non-boolean expressions inside the parentheses trumps whatever infinitely small performance boost would be gained by omission.